# C# How to build dll from net modules

Tags: c#, dll, module

In my project, I want to reuse some code for multiple binaries (.exe).

So, I decided to build a .dll from some sources and to include it in my .exe application thanks to csc.exe.

OK that works.

But now, I want to add a new level : I would like to build some net modules and then build my .dll which includes all net modules built before.

Is that possible ? How ?

Comment: What do you mean by "net modules"? I am unfamiliar with the term.

Comment: @Oded: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58scf68s.aspx

Comment: @Oded: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2005/02/12/371683.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible.  If you compile your projects all as .netmodules you can then link them into 1 single assembly.  Instructions can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/app-domains/build-multifile-assembly).

Comment: Dead link. Needs updating.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are going to end up with a multiple file assembly if you use the C# compiler to do that.

But `link.exe` (which comes with Visual C++) should be able to produce a single file assembly from a bunch of .netmodule files.

Answer (score 1):

```
/*for one file */
csc /target:module misource1.cs 

/*for multiple file */
csc /target:module misource1.cs misource2.cs misource3.cs
```

Target is Module so keep it before the source file names